What is the difference between the following two types of induction
In Simpson's book, the induction axiom for second order arithmetic is :
$ (0 \in X \wedge \forall n(n \in X \to n+1 \in X)) \to \forall n (n\in X) $.
However, the induction axiom for the subsystem of second order arithmetic $RCA_0$ is:
$(\varphi(0)\wedge \forall n (\varphi(n) \to \varphi(n+1))) \to \forall n \varphi(n) $.
My question is if we restrict the set $X$ in the first formula to be arithmetic, then is there any difference between these two induction axioms?

Not really.  The only difference is Simpson refers to objects being elements of a set, and $RCA_0$ refers to $\phi$ which appears to be an indication that an object has a property.  As, presumably, the set refers to elements for with a property holds, and $\phi$, presumably is a function that returns true if the element has a property they are equivalent.  At least, that's my take.  I really think it is only a difference of notation.

There would be no difference if the induction axiom scheme for $RCA_0$ were simply what you wrote. But in fact, it is the restricted case where $\varphi$ is required to be a $\Sigma^0_1$ formula. If you allow $\varphi$ to be an arbitrary first-order formula, that scheme would be correct in $ACA_0$, and if you allw arbitrary second-order formulas, it would be correct for full second-order arithmetic.

$X$ is proven to be the universal set? $\varphi$ is proven to be a universal predicate?
